Django models - How to Aggregate Many-to-Many Related Objects into Arrays?
so I started working with Django recently, I'm having a case of many-to-many relationship between Book and Author -as simple example- a book could have multiple authors.
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('Author', related_name='books')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

My goal is to fetch the data of Book, but the problem is when a book has multiple authors, I get the same book row for each of its authors, the question is can I have a book row with all its authors stored in a list ? instead of a row for each author.
Example of data fetching as JSON:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Good Omens",
        "authors__name": "Neil Gaiman"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Good Omens",
        "authors__name": "Terry Pratchett"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "authors__name": "J.R.R. Tolkien"
    }
]

So I want something like this instead:
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Good Omens",
        "authors__name": ["Neil Gaiman", "Terry Pratchett"]
    },

While it's easy to implement this via python code, I want a solution using model queries or ORM methods, to gain some performance and time since the data will be so big.
The following code shows a method responsible to get the data and to do some ordering and filtering, all using queries:
def __model_query(self, model_class, fields=None, enum_fields=None, order_by=None, search=None, field_search=None):
        queryset = model_class.objects.all()

        # Apply ordering if specified
        if order_by:
            field_name, sort_order = order_by
            if sort_order == "desc":
                queryset = queryset.order_by(f"-{field_name}")
            elif sort_order == "asc":
                queryset = queryset.order_by(field_name)

        # Apply general search if specified
        if search:
            search_filters = Q()
            for field in fields:
                search_filters |= Q(**{f"{field}__icontains": search})
            
            queryset = queryset.filter(search_filters)

        # Apply field-specific search if specified
        if field_search:
            search_filters = Q()
            for field, value in field_search.items():
                if enum_fields and field in enum_fields:
                    search_filters |= Q(**{f"{field}__exact": value})
                else:
                    search_filters |= Q(**{f"{field}__icontains": value})
            
            queryset = queryset.filter(search_filters)

        return queryset

I'm using sqlite3 db currently so I can't use any method related to Postgres db.
I really thank you who ever can help me with this, I hope I provided all the details needed.
I didn't try much solutions, just ones provided by ChatGPT but they are all failed.

You are using db.sqlite3 which dont support ArrayAgg so you can achieve your expected results using like this:
    books = Book.objects.values('id', 'title', 'authors__name')

    book_dict = {}
    for book in books:
        book_id = book['id']
        if book_id not in book_dict:
            book_dict[book_id] = {
                'id': book_id,
                'title': book['title'],
                'authors__name': []
            }
        if book['authors__name']:
            book_dict[book_id]['authors__name'].append(book['authors__name'])

    books_list = list(book_dict.values())


Thank you for the information, I think I'll switch to another db that supports it.
